# PrimeNG - Table / Treetable subscribe to changes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, primeng

I am using a primeng table with a rather large dataset.
I am not using lazy loading - there is one large get at the start which returns hundreds of rows. The requirement is to have all the rows up-front on page load.

I have implemented a series of manual filters to manipulate that dataset. These filters read from and manipulate a list of rows which were first populated on page load. At no point do these filters read from the server again.
When I click on a filter, there is a delay of a second or two where the underlying rows for the datatable are updated and the UI is updated.
It appears that when this happens, it's not asynchronous - I say this because nothing else can be clicked when this occurs. The application effectively hangs during this period which isn't a great user experience.

I think a way to work around this would be to somehow subscribe to the event and show a loader while this is happening.
There are outputs on the datatable which fire events when certain actions occur (onSort, onNodeExpand and so on) but these run as soon as the action occurs and don't provide an observable.
I have seen docs related to changeDetectorRef which may be what I'm after but I don't completely understand it.

Does anyone know if I can get the event while it is loading?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't see a way around this. The table / component was loading too big of an object which meant any in-memory browser filtering made the application hang.
I moved all of my filtering to the server.